# Java.lang.NullPointerException error when adding Sandbox Tester in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I keep getting the Java.lang.NullPointerException error when trying to add a new user to the Sandbox Tester list in Users and Roles within iTunes Connect. I had just deleted all the testers in that list and was trying to start from scratch with new testers, emails and passwords. None had been used before. Is this an error on the Apple server side? Should I just try again tomorrow?

Comment: Just got this same issue myself. I'll try again tomorrow (1-7-17)..

Comment: I was able to add a test user about six hours after the posting of the question.

Comment: Still seeing this error.

Comment: same here, any progress on your side ?

Comment: Same happens with me. I've filled a bug report, let's hope they will fix it soon.

Comment: I'm having the same issue this morning, I also can't login to itunes with existing sandbox users to test in-app purchases. Anyone having that issue this morning as well?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue.  Signed in to iTunes Connect several times with different accounts today, no issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not just you unfortunately. It seems like their servers are down at the moment - I'd say try again tomorrow.

Comment: Working for me now. Looks like it was just down, as I'm using the exact same credentials, etc, for sign up.

Answer (score 2):

Does your password have an uppercase letter, lowercase letter and number?   Looks like their password validation handler is messed up.  I just submitted a bug report about it.

I was having the same problem for days until I figured this out.

Comment: Actually, the test user I was finally able to add six hours after submitting this question did have a password with upper and lower case, numbers and punctuation.